# How to get closest minimum value in a column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named meals and I want the id of the meal whose start time is greater than current time but minimum among those satisfying this criteria and if there is no value found then I want the id of meal with minimum start value.
Structure of table is like this:

1. id: int(3)
2. start: time
3. end: time
4. name: varchar(20)

Please provide the sql statement if possible, I've tried a lot but I'm getting errors.

Comment: can you provide a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/ with sample data and expected output?

Comment: `select abs(val-$whatever) as min_diff ... order by min_diff asc`

Comment: What have you tried so far and what errors are you getting? SO is not a "write my query" service.

Comment: Can you show us some things you tried?

Comment: maybe you can give us a table in picture (.jpg) from excel or something maybe? so we can get the imagination of yours.

Comment: Are you speaking about looking for the closest value compared to the one you have selected within the ones that are less than the selected one?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a788a/1/0

Comment: Above is the link for sql fiddle

Comment: select case when cast('".date('H:i:s')."' as time)>max(start) then (select id from meals where id not in (select big.id from meals as big join meals as small on big.start>small.start where status='a' as bigger) and status='a') else id end 'ids' from (select * from meals where status='a');

Comment: I tried several other versions too but I am getting errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this with `order by` and `limit`:

```
select m.*
from meals m
where m.time
order by (m.time > $time) desc, -- put the later meals first
         time asc               -- put the next meal first
limit 1;
```

This handles both getting the next value and wrapping to get the first value.

I should note:  for solving this type of problem, you don't need to take the difference.  This is useful, because you can use the same idea for strings, as well as dates and times.  You just need to be able to compare two values and use them for sort keys.

The expression `(m.time > $time) desc` is a boolean expression that is treated as an integer.  In an integer context, booleans are treated as 0 for false and 1 for true.  The `desc` puts the "1"s before the "0"s, so this puts later times (relative to `$time`) first, and then earlier times.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I didn't wanted to use the limit but I've been stuck on this for a while and it seems to do the trick. :)

Comment: Please explain the logic for using order by (m.time > $time) desc. I can't understand it.